# How do I add/change .NET Web API's default Json message response properties?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Using the example of an unauthorized call in web API, it will provide a response as per this.

[image]

1. Is there a way to change the default property name "Message" to another name like "Reason"/"Description" for non-success API responses?
2. Is it possible to add a new property like "Status"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes just use  If you want to change the structure of the Josn response return from the server you can create new response by using follwing code in asp.net mvc app .

```
  // here you can use your own properties  which then can be send to client .
  return Json(new { Status= false ,Description = response.Message });
```

if you have  the controller method then you should return JsonResult

If you are looking for a generic solution then please have a look at this article it might help you .

http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/wrapping-asp.net-web-api-responses-for-consistency-and-to-provide-additional-information

Comment: Hi @Yashveer, I'm actually looking for something more in-depth where it has not even reach to the controller action. Be it 401 unauthorized, or some other non-200 responses.

Comment: @Kes can you please provide more information  like where do you want this implementation . One possible answer is what is  in another answer is to use AuthorizeAttribute . Create a custom class that will be called when you have Authorize attribute is present on controller .

Comment: @Kes specify your project type also what have you tried so far

Comment: Basically I need to standardize the json responses from the Web api. For example, if all actions returns "status" as part of every response denoting success or failure, I would want other responses handled by .net to return "status" as well (authorization being one of it). By adding how custom authorization, I would be resolving only authorization. How do I cover all the other responses like { "Message" : "The request is invalid." }?

Comment: So id we see it means you will have a base class Which will have Stattus , Message as String and all other ViewModels will inherit from this . So all controller menthod will return something which has base class . In this way you will always have these properties . This iwll be true for all controller methods but for Aurthorization you still need to have a custom class

Comment: I have that covered for all controller actions as mentioned. It is more on the response handled by .net itself before it even reach the action.

Comment: @Kes :- I added a kink oin my answer I think this is what you are looking for I hope it is useful for your question

Comment: Thanks @Yashveer
It looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: This is not solution for the question @Kes asked originally. This should not be marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a custom AuthorizeAttribute.

```
 public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public CustomAuthorizeAttribute ()
        {

        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Authorize(actionContext))
                {
                    return;
                }
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //create custom response
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.OK,
                    customresponse
                );
                return;
            }

        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            //create custom unauthorized response

            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.OK,
                customunauthorizedresponse
            );
            return;
        }

        private bool Authorize(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            //authorization logics
        }


    }
```

in your api controller method you can use `[CustomAuthorizeAttribute]` insted of `[Authorize]`

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointer on the custom authorization. However is there a way to apply this globally instead of just authorization? Because there might be other responses like { "Message" : "The request is invalid." }.

Comment: This is not what @Kes was asking.. He needs something that can control the default "Message" attribute generated from web api.